# How to fetch object for a particular index in nsmutablearray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uilocalnotification

hi i am facing some problem in getting right kind of description in scheduleNotification method i am getting sigbart due to remedyarray going out of bounds .How to fetch object  for that particular index in nsmutablearray

I am getting wrong description in scheduleNotification method that is in notify.alertbody ,
In cellforrow I m getting correct description

i am not able to get right description since i cant do objectatindex in schedulenotification method ..

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";
    PPtableCell *cell=(PPtableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell=[[PPtableCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.cellDelegate = self;
    }

    cell.notifyMe.on = NO;
    cell.remedyTextLabel.text=[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"RemedyTxtDic"];

    return cell;
 }

    else {
        return nil;
    }

}

- (UILocalNotification *)scheduleNotification :(int)remedyID {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {

        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];

        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        NSLog(@"%d",remedyID);

        NSString *descriptionBody=[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:remedyID]objectForKey:@"RemedyTxtDic"];

        NSLog(@"%@",descriptionBody);

        notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithString:descriptionBody];
```

Comment: How are you calling scheduleNotification:, and where do you get remedyID from ? What do you get for the log of remedyID?

Comment: @rock : when I was indenting your code, I found one extra **}** Please check with your original code, as you may have missed to post somthing between if and else.

Comment: @rdelmar...sorry I forgot to add cell.remedyID=[[remedy array objectatindex:index path.row]objectforkey:@"remedyID"]; in cellfor

Comment: When I put nslog to description in schedulenotification method then there itself wrong description is shown like if I click 1st cell it shows description of 4th cell. That's my problem array is going out of bounds

Comment: I need to get object of that index if array ...now what's happening is if I click say 20th object it is searching for 20th index which is not there that is why I am getting out of bounds.    Akv } doesn't concern my problem so np :)

Comment: You still didn't say how (and from where) you call scheduleNotification. You should add that code to your question. I really can't diagnose your problem without seeing that.

Comment: and obviously I cant use objectatindex in schedulenotification

Comment: I am calling in notificationchanged method where I am parameter remedyID.        [self schedulenotufication:remedyID]

Answer (score 2):

- Small point, but `-objectAtIndex:` takes an `NSUInteger`, not an `int`.
- I assume `remedyArray` an instance variable(?)

I don't think your problem is in the method you're showing, aside from the fact that the argument to `-objectAtIndex:` is the wrong type it should work ok.  Can you show the code that is calling `scheduleNotification:`?

If I were you I wouldn't use an object's array index to locate it, you're could get into trouble with race conditions and situations where the array changes around the time a notification is schedules.  Instead, you should be doing a linear search through the array, or if that's too slow, you should keep a hash map of it.

Or even better, your Remedy object should be an NSManagedObject, and then you get all the table handling and finder functionality for free.

Comment: Objectatindex does take int value

Comment: You might wanna look at your docs again, the message's first argument is typed NSUInteger.  It'll take an (int), but you'll get into trouble if that int ever holds a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i was able to solve it ..This is my code

```
- (UILocalNotification *)scheduleNotification :(int)remedyID
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil)
    {
        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        NSString *descriptionBody;

        for (int i=0; i<remedyArray.count; i++)
        {
            int arrayid = [[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"RemedyID"]intValue];
            if (arrayid == remedyID)
            {
                descriptionBody=[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"RemedyTxtDic"];
                break;
            }

        }

        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components setDay:25];
        [components setMonth:1];
        [components setYear:2013];
        [components setMinute:45];
        [components setHour:11];

        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];


        notif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithString:descriptionBody];
        notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

        notif.fireDate = date;

        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:notif.alertBody
                                                             forKey:@"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey"];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];

        return notif;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could replace your `for` loop with this: `for( NSNumber * arrayID in [ remedyArray valueForKey:@"RemedyID" ] ) { if ( [ arrayID integerValue ] == remedyID ) { ... } }`